# Препроцессор С++

Tags: c++

```
#define     XCLASS_BOOL              0x1000
#define     XTYP_ADVSTART           (0x0030 | XCLASS_BOOL)
```

Почему используется такое [код](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms648716) препроцессора!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что бы при изменении XCLASSBOOL автоматически менялся XTYP_ADVSTART. (Не получается ввести символ _ - текст результата странно форматируется). Видимо по смыслу задачи они каким-то образом связаны.

Скобочки используют для того, чтобы XTYP_ADVSTART, использованное в каком-либо выражении вычислялось с правильным приоритетом.